# Getting method, range of object worksheet failed while trying to clear the content in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear the contents of the cell after clicking the ok button in a message pop up window.

When the pop up window disappears, after clicking ok button umpteen times, the script terminates by throwing the below error

> Run time error '-2147417848(80010108)':
>   Method 'Range of object'_Worksheet'Failed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("N4:O4")
If Not Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If (Range("E9") = "" Or Range("F9") = "") Then
    MsgBox "Reopen Date and Closed Date should not be populated before calculating the Benefit Begin Date and Maximum Benefit Date"
    Sheets("Calculation Tool").Range("N4").Clear ----->Code written to clear the cells
   Else
      If (Range("N4") = "" Or Range("O4") = "") Then
         Set b1 = Sheets("Calculation Tool").CommandButton22
         b1.Enabled = False
      Else
         Set b1 = Sheets("Calculation Tool").CommandButton22
         b1.Enabled = True
      End If
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: try this;     `Dim Output As Integer
    If Output = 1 Then Sheets("Calculation Tool").Range("N4").Clear`

Comment: You don't need the () around your two If/Or ranges

Comment: Is "Calculation Tool" the name of the sheet containing this code?

Comment: Yes, it is name of the sheet containing this code.

Comment: What action should be done to set the variable "output" = 1 in the above suggested code please? or should I need to just assign the value "1" to the variable "output" after the "msgbox" statement?

Comment: If this code is in the `Calculation Tool` sheet module, then you'll need to disable / re-enable events - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761530/vba-worksheet-change-event-bypass

Comment: Hi @BigBen should this enable/disable events be written inside the Worksheet_Change sub or should it be written as a separate sub? Can you able to help me on this please?

Comment: Within - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure)

Comment: Hi @BigBen Thanks for the input.. I will get this tried and get back to you if I encounter any issues while implementing the same.

Answer (score 0):

*I wanted to tell @BigBen that [his suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393594/getting-method-range-of-object-worksheet-failed-while-trying-to-clear-the-conte#comment91758939_52393594) worked for me, but my low rep won't allow me to comment. The answer field is the only way of expression for me!
So I might as well formulate a valid answer, here it goes. :)*

So I had the same problem within a Worksheet_Change event macro, in this casual event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RangeToCheck As Range

    Set RangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("O3:O32")
```

(above is the line that triggered randomly that Run time error '-2147417848(80010108)' you encountered; on with the script)

```
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, RangeToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Value = VBA.Replace(Target.Value, ".", ",")
        Debug.Print Target.Address, Target.Value
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not in RangeToCheck"
    End If

End Sub
```

Following BigBen's link, I found that the following code works fine :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RangeToCheck As Range

On Error GoTo enableEventsOn:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set RangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("O3:O32")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, RangeToCheck) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Value = VBA.Replace(Target.Value, ".", ",")
        Debug.Print Target.Address, Target.Value
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not in RangeToCheck"
    End If

enableEventsOn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```