# Run this Worksheet_Calculate when opening workbook without running my Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Right now my process is working correctly, with the help of this community, however, I need this Worksheet_Calculate to NOT execute the Macro (*MacroRuns* for example) when the workbook opens, but I still need it to function the same way it is currently, after the workbook is opened.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

### The Code I Am Using:

**in ThisWorkbook**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    TargetStart
End Sub
```

**in the target sheet's code window**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
    TargetCalc Me
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**in Module 1**

```
Option Explicit

Public TargetValue As Variant
Private Const cTarget As String = "C3"

Sub TargetCalc(ws as Worksheet)
    If ws.Range(cTarget) <> TargetValue Then
'this is where I would like the code to say something like, "if workbook just opened, exit -- otherwise continue. If this is even possible.
       Call MacroRuns
        TargetValue = ws.Range(cTarget).Value
    End If
End Sub

Sub TargetStart()
    TargetValue = Sheet1.Range(cTarget).Value
End Sub


Sub MacroRuns()

    Call UpdateMsgBox

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Worksheet change event bypass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761530/vba-worksheet-change-event-bypass). Even though it's a different event, it sounds like you possibly need the same solution.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen I've read that but it doesn't seem to pertain to my question of how to exit a worksheet_calculate after my macro has been run 1 time. If somehow it does answer my quiestion, I don't understand how to implement that into my code listed above.

Comment: Within `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before `TargetCalc Me`, and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after `TargetCalc.Me`.

Comment: Thank you so much man, that worked! The only other thing that's related to this is to somehow "NOT run the macro when I open the workbook, but run normally after the workbook is open." Is this a simple answer, or should I post a separate question. I have looked for this type of question on this site but haven't seen anything. Thanks for your help..

Comment: I'd post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can solve your problem:

**In ThisWorkbook:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("NameHere").Range("A1") = True
End Sub
```

**In the target sheet's code window:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Worksheets("NameHere").Range("A1") Then MacroRuns
    Worksheets("NameHere").Range("A1") = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to clarify my question since BigBen pointed out that my original question was a duplicate. He showed me how to keep it from looping, now I just need to know how to keep it from running my macro when I open the workbook.

Comment: I do not understand what you need. Using my code, MacroRuns will run only once when the worksheet is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this arrangement.

```
Public StartUp As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartUp = True
    TargetStart
End Sub

Sub TargetCalc(ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.Range(cTarget) <> TargetValue Then
        If Not StartUp Then MacroRuns
        StartUp = False
        TargetValue = ws.Range(cTarget).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

or, perhaps you prefer it to be like this.

```
Sub TargetCalc(ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.Range(cTarget) <> TargetValue Then
        If Not StartUp Then
            MacroRuns
            TargetValue = ws.Range(cTarget).Value
        End If
        StartUp = False
    End If
End Sub
```